# Pandas: Reorder values in one column within the groups that are created based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

My data is already sorted by groups based on one column. And within each group I am trying to reorder the values in another column. The below example illustrates what I mean:

Currently my data looks like this, its sorted by the carrier name. The 3rd column shows what type of products they're holding. However, I would like chicken to be first on the list for every carrier, so that it looks like the second table below.

| Name | Amount | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carrier A | 1 | Apples |
| Carrier A | 9 | Oranges |
| Carrier A | 8 | Bananas |
| Carrier A | 10 | Chicken |
| Carrier A | 28 | Total |
| Carrier B | 9 | Apples |
| Carrier B | 4 | Oranges |
| Carrier B | 6 | Bananas |
| Carrier B | 9 | Chicken |
| Carrier B | 28 | Total |
| Carrier C | 5 | Apples |
| Carrier C | 8 | Oranges |
| Carrier C | 9 | Bananas |
| Carrier C | 10 | Chicken |
| Carrier C | 32 | Total |

The below table is what I am trying to achieve.

| Name | Amount | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carrier A | 10 | Chicken |
| Carrier A | 1 | Apples |
| Carrier A | 9 | Oranges |
| Carrier A | 8 | Bananas |
| Carrier A | 18 | Total |
| Carrier B | 9 | Chicken |
| Carrier B | 9 | Apples |
| Carrier B | 4 | Oranges |
| Carrier B | 6 | Bananas |
| Carrier B | 19 | Total |
| Carrier C | 10 | Chicken |
| Carrier C | 5 | Apples |
| Carrier C | 8 | Oranges |
| Carrier C | 9 | Bananas |
| Carrier C | 22 | Total |

Is there a way to do this with pandas? Instinctively I looked at feeding df.sort_value both the Name and Product columns, but realized that it can only sort by ascending and descending order.

Also the order of values in the "Name" column must be preserved for my task. In this example, its already ordered alphabetically, but its not necessarily the case nor my intention in my actual dataset.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Edit: added details for additional clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.CategoricalDType` to accomplish that:

```
# create your ordered list
cat = ['Chicken'] + sorted([p for p in df["Product"].unique()
                                  if not p in ['Chicken', 'Total']]) + ['Total']

# set as category
df = df.astype({'Product': pd.CategoricalDtype(cat, ordered=True)})
```

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 15 entries, 0 to 14
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------   --------------  -----
 0   Name     15 non-null     object
 1   Amount   15 non-null     int64
 2   Product  15 non-null     category
dtypes: category(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 595.0+ bytes
```

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Name', 'Product'])
         Name  Amount  Product
3   Carrier A      10  Chicken
0   Carrier A       1   Apples
2   Carrier A       8  Bananas
1   Carrier A       9  Oranges
4   Carrier A      28    Total
8   Carrier B       9  Chicken
5   Carrier B       9   Apples
7   Carrier B       6  Bananas
6   Carrier B       4  Oranges
9   Carrier B      28    Total
13  Carrier C      10  Chicken
10  Carrier C       5   Apples
12  Carrier C       9  Bananas
11  Carrier C       8  Oranges
14  Carrier C      32    Total
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the order in "Name" should be preserved. Your code works in this example because Name is already sorted alphabetically. But in the actual dataset, its not sorted that way but the originally order must still be preserved. I've updated my question, thanks

Comment: Sorry, please disregard above comment - this solution works perfectly if I define another sorting mechanism after your suggested code to sort "Name" again.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in a step by step fashion

```py
# Get unique categories and convert to list
products = list(df.Product.unique())
# Move "Chicken" to front of list
products.insert(0, products.pop(products.index("Chicken")))
# Convert "Product" column to categorical with the order of the products list
df.Product = pd.Categorical(df.Product, products)
# Sort based on two columns
df = df.sort_values(["Name", "Product"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. As with the other solution, unfortunately I failed to indicate that the order in which the Carriers are shown must be preserved. In my example, they are already ordered alphabetically, however this isn't the case nor my intention in my actual dataset. I have updated my question with this additional ask.